# Upgraded Python and broke everything

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

Today I upgraded python to python3/python3.8 and broke everything

I tried to uninstall python and install it again, but it's not possible
I don't know can replace the folder somehow?
But now I have a problem, I tried to google it and also did what I can but I failed...
It seems that something deleted the python folder and now some files are missing
I have no idea what to do now, my latin is at the end :/

```
root@laptop-server:/home/toor/byob/web-gui# sudo apt-get install python3.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3.8 is already the newest version (3.8.5-1~20.04).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm10 linux-headers-5.4.0-58 linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-59 linux-headers-5.4.0-59-generic
  linux-headers-5.4.0-60 linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic linux-image-5.4.0-59-generic
  linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-58-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-59-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-60-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-58-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-59-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-60-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3-contextlib2 (0.6.0-2) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fd48ad54740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
dpkg: error processing package python3-contextlib2 (--configure):
 installed python3-contextlib2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-contextlib2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@laptop-server:/home/toor/byob/web-gui#
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3-contextlib2 (0.6.0-2) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fd48ad54740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
dpkg: error processing package python3-contextlib2 (--configure):
 installed python3-contextlib2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-contextlib2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@laptop-server:/home/toor/byob/web-gui#
```

Comment: Do not uninstall the system Python! It will mess up important system tools. Try to reinstall the system Python version and install the new version in parallel. On Ubuntu a `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` might help.

Answer (score 0):

a friend you just need to uninstall python if not working go to the drive where you give python the location to install the folder and from there delete it. most importantly make the backup for python files after this process again try to install python

I gave this suggestion because the same situation occurred on my device I did this same process that i told you and reinstalled the python

Comment: I cant thats the problem, i get the same error